# Probability question re: odds of winning and number of wins

Tags: probability

I'm trying to apply the math in [this thread about odds of winning a raffle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91998/probability-of-winning-a-prize-in-a-raffle) to my own situation but am having difficulty.

Assume the following:

- Each month for one year in total, a raffle is held.
- There are 3,125 tickets sold for each raffle.
- There are 135 winning tickets for each raffle.
- I purchase 100 tickets in each raffle.

**What I'm Trying to Calculate (Unsuccessfully)**

(1) (a) What are the odds that any 1 of my 100 tickets is drawn in the raffle in any given month?  (b) In any given year?

(2) (a) What are the odds that 2 or more of my 100 tickets are drawn in the raffle in any given month? (b) In any given year?

(3) (a) What is the expected / most likely number of my tickets that will be drawn in the raffle in any given month? (b) In any given year?

Regarding the first question above, when I try to apply the math in the previously cited thread, I get insanely high odds (98.8%) that at least 1 of my 100 tickets will be drawn as a winner in any given month.  That seems way too high to me.

Regarding the second and third question above, I don't even know how to go about answering them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $3125 \choose 135$ ways to choose the winning tickets and $3025 \choose 135$ ways to choose the winning tickets without choosing any of yours.  Your probability of losing is then $\frac {3025 \choose 135}{3125 \choose 135} \approx 0.03667$ so your chance of winning is $96.333\%$  That is not as good as you thought, but quite good.  To not win at all in a year, you have to lose $12$ times in a row, with probability $0.03667^{12}$, which is very small.  The chance of two wins or more in a year is likewise almost certain.  For the expected number of wins, each ticket has $\frac {135}{3125}$ chance of winning, so by the linearity of expectation the expected number is $\frac {100\cdot 135}{3125}=4.32$ each month and $12$ times that for a year.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!  Can you explain the linearity of expectation and the calculation behind it a bit more?  I can't figure out how to calculate the 4.32 you mentioned.

Comment: As I said, the expected number of wins for each ticket is $\frac {135}{3125}$, so you just multiply by $100$ for all your tickets.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) has a good discussion