# Probability of winning at least several raffle tickets

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My question is quite similar to this: [Probability of winning a prize in a raffle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91998/probability-of-winning-a-prize-in-a-raffle), but what if I want to know the probability of at least a certain number of times?

Let's modify that example in the aforementioned question a little bit into this:

> There are 1600 Tickets and 40 Prizes. This time I'm buying 20 Tickets.

The question: What is the probability of **winning at least 4 prizes**?

Through simulation, I get somewhere around ≈0.0012 . Is there a systematic way I can calculate the correct probability?

It is also calculated that winning at least once is ≈0.3992 (applying the method from the aforementioned question)

Comment: Subtract the probability of winning fewer than four prizes from $1$.

Comment: While I know how to calculate not winning at all, I've spent another 25 minutes figuring how to calculate the probability of winning exactly once but failed. Would you mind sharing how to calculate winning fewer than four prizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of winning exactly $k$ of the $40$ prizes when buying $20$ of the $1600$ tickets is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{40}{k}\dbinom{1560}{20 - k}}{\dbinom{1600}{20}}$$
where $\binom{40}{k}$ is the number of ways of selecting exactly $k$ of the $40$ winning tickets, $\binom{1560}{20 - k}$ is the number of ways of selecting exactly $20 - k$ of the $1600 - 40 = 1560$ non-winning tickets, and $\binom{1600}{20}$ is the number of ways of selecting $20$ of the $1600$ available tickets.

Therefore, the probability of winning less than $4$ prizes when buying $20$ of the $1600$ tickets is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{3} \frac{\dbinom{40}{k}\dbinom{1560}{20 - k}}{\dbinom{1600}{20}} = \frac{\dbinom{40}{0}\dbinom{1560}{20}}{
\dbinom{1600}{20}} + \frac{\dbinom{40}{1}\dbinom{1560}{19}}{\dbinom{1600}{20}} + \frac{\dbinom{40}{2}\dbinom{1560}{18}}{\dbinom{1600}{20}} + \frac{\dbinom{40}{3}\dbinom{1560}{17}}{\dbinom{1600}{20}}$$
To find the probability of winning at least four prizes, subtract the probability of winning fewer than four prizes from $1$.