# What is the probability of winning exactly twice in eight draws of a raffle?

Tags: probability

A raffle is held with 8 prizes, you buy 120 tickets and there are a total of 9,516 tickets sold, tickets are replaced once they are drawn. What are the chances of winning exactly 2 prizes (can be any 2).

Comment: "Tickets are replaced once they are drawn."   How does this work?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that the same ticket can be drawn multiple times, as each time they are drawn they are put back.

Comment: Hi! Please provide some additional context, such as whether this question is from a course, and if so, which one, and what specific topic you are studying at the moment; what you know that you think might be relevant; what things you've tried but perhaps have gotten stuck; and so forth. Please edit your original post to include this information, as opposed to responding in a comment. This will help to avoid downvotes and closevotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly similar problem to the one here: [Probability of winning a prize in a raffle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91998/probability-of-winning-a-prize-in-a-raffle?rq=1)

Instead of solving for $(1 - P(\textrm{0 prizes}))$, you want to solve for $P($2 prizes$)$. The general form of $P$ comes from the binomial distribution. Given $n$ trials, the probability of having exactly $k$ successes is:

$$P(x=k) = {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $$

where $p$ is the probability of any single trial's success.

Think of winning each prize as a trial. Then $n$ is the total number of prizes available, 8, and $k$ is how many prizes of interest, 2. This $p$ is the probability that any single ticket may win the raffle: for drawing from a raffle with replacement, this is the number of tickets you have divided by the total number of tickets. Thus:

$$P(k \;\textrm{prizes}) = {8 \choose k} \Bigg(\frac{120}{9516}\Bigg)^k \Bigg(1-\frac{120}{9516} \Bigg)^{8-k} $$